# ModSecurity Rule 973338

Tags: xss, javascript, apache, centos, mod-security

ModSecurity blocked access due to the following:

> [msg "XSS Filter - Category 3: Javascript URI Vector"] [data "Matched
>   Data: esrco found within ARGS:as_email:hearsesesrcool@yahoo.com"]
>   [severity "CRITICAL"]

Why does the string `esrco` trigger an error?  I tried googling any javascript implications and could not find any.  Should I disable this rule?

Comment: Are you sure it's the string "esrco" itself which is triggering this?

Comment: I copied and pasted the exact error message that I was getting in the log.

Comment: Potentially helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34027786/1060378

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the 'src' in esrco that [triggers the rule](https://lists.owasp.org/pipermail/owasp-modsecurity-core-rule-set/2013-January/001284.html).

I had to deactivate that rule, because it was impossible to forbid the string src across the whole application.

Comment: I had to look for a while to find out that you were correct (because the message seemed to contradict you). Next time, please include some source our backup to any claims. I have added the source to your answer.