# ModSecurity rule 941160 triggered by WordPress legacy-widget-preview

Tags: owasp, mod-security

We have an issue with ModSecurity rule 941160 being triggered by the WordPress feature legacy-widget-preview because the request to upload an image file into the widget matches "<img src="

The ModSecurity log file has this:

`Apache-Error: [file "apache2_util.c"] [line 271] [level 3] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match "(?i:(?:<\\\\\\\\w[\\\\\\\\s\\\\\\\\S]*[\\\\\\\\s\\\\\\\\/]|['\\\\"](?:[\\\\\\\\s\\\\\\\\S]*[\\\\\\\\s\\\\\\\\/])?)(?:on(?:d(?:e(?:vice(?:(?:orienta|mo)tion|proximity|found|light)|livery(?:success|error)|activate)|r(?:ag(?:e(?:n(?:ter|d)|xit)|(?:gestur|leav)e|start|drop|over)|op)|i(?:s(?:c(?:hargingtimechange ..." at ARGS:legacy-widget-preview[instance][raw][text]. [file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec_vendor_configs/OWASP3/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf"] [line "199"] [id "941160"] [msg "NoScript XSS InjectionChecker: HTML Injection"] [data "Matched Data: <img src= found within ARGS:legacy-widget-preview[instance][raw][text]: fg<img src=\\\\x22https://XXXXXXXXX.DE/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/LMakr-0gQrGv.png\\\\x22 alt=\\\\x22\\\\x22 width=\\\\x22300\\\\x22 height=\\\\x22300\\\\x22 class=\\\\x22alignnone size-full wp-image-680\\\\x22 />"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-xss"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/242"] [hostname "XXXXXXXXX.DE"] [uri "/wp-admin/widgets.php"] [unique_id "YVI58h7F-ItLX29cwjsTQAAzAI"]`

I presume the key part here is:

Matched Data: <img src= found within ARGS:legacy-widget-preview[instance][raw][text]

I have attempted to write a ModSecurity rule (below) but it's not at a working point yet. I'm stuck on the last line and I'd really appreciate if someone can advise how it should be written?

````
#This creates an exception to the rule excluding this phrase
SecRule REQUEST_LINE "@contains /wp-admin/widgets.php?legacy-widget-preview%5BidBase%5D=text&legacy-widget-preview%5Binstance%5D%5Bencoded" \
    "id:10001,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    msg:'modsec2.whitelist.conf exemption',\
    log,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=941160;ARGS:text,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=941160;REQUEST_HEADERS:'<img src='\"```
````

Comment: I found an answer to a [similar question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187743/modsecurity-rule-973338?rq=1) that suggests it may just be the "src" that is being blocked.


That answer is about a different ModSecurity rule. I reviewed rule 941160 and it doesn't include either 'src' or 'img'. At least not in plain text. There's a lot of syntax I do not understand and I'm unsure how to test it further.

Is it best practice to find the exact ARGS required for ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=941160 in my rule?

Could I just add an "allow,\" line to let the request through?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the CRS WordPress rule exclusions enabled? Those handle WordPress-specific false positives with the CRS. That is a good place to start, if you haven't already done that.

I'm not sure you want to be looking at `ARGS:text` or the `REQUEST_HEADERS` collection. You were correct with what you initially said: looking at the log sample, the variable you're interested in is `ARGS:legacy-widget-preview[instance][raw][text]`.

Based on that log entry, a rule exclusion applying to *all* locations might look like so:

```
#
# -- CRS Rule Exclusion: 941160 - NoScript XSS InjectionChecker: HTML Injection
#
# Disable rule for the legacy-widget-preview due to issues when uploading an
# image file into the widget
#
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 941160 !ARGS:legacy-widget-preview[instance][raw][text]
```

That would need to be placed **after** the `Include` directive that includes the Core Rule Set.

Alternatively, a rule exclusion applying to *only* to the `/wp-admin/widgets.php` location might look like so:

```
#
# -- CRS Rule Exclusion: 941160 - NoScript XSS InjectionChecker: HTML Injection
#
# Disable rule for the legacy-widget-preview due to issues when uploading an
# image file into the widget
#
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@endsWith /wp-admin/widgets.php" \
    "id:1001,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=941160;ARGS:legacy-widget-preview[instance][raw][text]"
```

That would need to be placed **before** the `Include` directive that includes the Core Rule Set.